# What does Queue Data structure with locks entail?

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, parallel-processing, queue

I am trying to understand different data structures with parallel programming to prepare for an interview.

I was wondering if I were to implement a queue with a lock, what kind of functionality do I have to extend?

The reason I asked is that it seems like I just have to ensure that one thread is allowed to access the queue at any given time, is there more to it?

Comment: Yes you just have to make sure queue elements are accessed in synchronized way to make sure two writes does not affect this. Also depending on restrictions to read correct updated value at all time, you should give read access too in synchronized way.

Answer (score 0):

A question of extending a serial data structure to be suitable for parallel or concurrent programming is a tricky one. It's not as easy as taking an implementation and protecting every function or method with a lock; just ensuring that only one thread is allowed to access/modify a container at any given time is not enough.

For an example, let's take the queue from the standard C++ library: `std::queue`. The typical piece of code to pop an element `e` out of a queue `q` is the following:

```
if (!q.empty()) {
    e = q.front();
    q.pop();
}
```

Let's assume a lock is added into the queue implementation and each method of the queue is internally protected with the lock. Unfortunately, this piece of code still remains unsafe for concurrency. If multiple threads pop elements from the queue, the result of `empty()` becomes unreliable as soon as the lock is released inside the method, because another thread may pop the last element before this thread. Another problem is that two or more threads may get the same value out of `front()` but then pop different items out of the queue.

To work correctly, the above piece of code as a whole should be protected with the lock, which means the lock should be external to the queue. Alternatively, a new method which implements the above operation should be added to the queue, and existing methods should be removed or declared unsafe; i.e. the interface of the container may need changes for thread safety.